# Windows 10 PC freezes during some games, hard drive light stays on

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, freeze, amd-ryzen

I've recently upgraded most of the components in my PC, I changed motherboard, RAM and CPU:

- Ryzen 3600
- MSI B450 Tomahawk Max
- 16GB Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 3000MHz

I'm still running the system on the old Crucial BX300 SSD. I did not wipe and start afresh when I changed the components.

I've got a problem where playing some games the system will completely freeze up for about 15 seconds at a time, the hard drive light stays lit. Eventually, it will suddenly come back to life and everything works fine.

This also occasionally happens on the desktop, but rather than completely freezing, I'm still able to move the mouse and click on things, but nothing will open until it unfreezes.

I've never had to actually restart the PC to get past the freezes.

I've checked temperatures. GPU is fine and never goes above 70degC, the CPU is still on the stock cooler and idles around mid 40s, reaches 80degC occasionally under load, but normally hovers around 75degC under load.

I'll probably try doing a clean install of Windows, but this feels more like a hardware issue?

Comment: I've had weird things like this happen after upgrading the same components you listed.  It could be a potential driver issue between what drivers you have installed and the new components.  You can try installing new drivers for your devices and see what happens.  But in my case, the last time I performed a hardware upgrade (new motherboard, CPU, RAM) I had to also reinstall Windows because it would blue screen shortly after booting.

Comment: I've updated the BIOS to the latest version now and run a 4 pass memtest (no errors found). I'll see how I get on, but if it still happens I'll just format the drive and start afresh

Answer (score 1):

So I found the culprit. Event viewer showed a warning against **storahci** every time a freeze occurred:

```
Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.
```

Some googling suggested I disable AHCI power management in the Windows Power options, since I did that I haven't had any freezes (in about 4 hours at least) - I was getting them every 15-20 minutes before so I'm going to say it's fixed.